# Flyweight Pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I came across [FlyWeight Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flyweight-design-pattern/) described in the link. In the example provided , I believe only 2 implementations of player objects will be created. Wouldn't the weapons variable be overridden each time a player object is created?

Comment: no, it would not. But if you want a better answer, you're going to have to ask [a better question here](help/how-to-ask). Reduce the code you're talking about, put it in your post, and then explain why you think that would happen - _after_ running the code in your IDE and simply following what happens there. Good bet you'll discover why they don't get overriden on your own and instead of updating your post, just end up deleting it because after spending some more time on it, the answer is suddenly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted on [Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flyweight-design-pattern/) constructs only two mutable objects. 
As can be expected, each time `PlayerFactory` returns a player, it overrides the `weapon` of one of the two objects. 
This can be demonstrated easily:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class CounterStrike
{

    private static String[] playerType = {"Terrorist", "CounterTerrorist"};
    private static String[] weapons = {"AK-47", "Maverick", "Gut Knife", "Desert Eagle"};

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("-------  Construction of Players  ----------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Player p = PlayerFactory.getPlayer(getRandPlayerType());
            p.assignWeapon(getRandWeapon());
            p.mission();
            players.add(p);
        }

        System.out.println("-------  Printout all players ----------------");
        for(Player p : players) {
            p.mission();
        }
    }

    public static String getRandPlayerType()
    {
        // Will return 0 or 1
        int randInt =  new Random().nextInt(playerType.length);
        return playerType[randInt];
    }

    public static String getRandWeapon()
    {
        // Will return an integer between 0 inclusive and 5 exclusive
        int randInt = new Random().nextInt(weapons.length);
        return weapons[randInt];
    }
}

interface Player
{
    void assignWeapon(String weapon);
    void mission();
}

class Terrorist implements Player
{
    private final String TASK;
    private String weapon;

    public Terrorist()
    {
        TASK = "PLANT A BOMB";
    }

    @Override
    public void assignWeapon(String weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    @Override
    public void mission()
    {
        System.out.println("Terrorist with weapon " + weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}

class CounterTerrorist implements Player
{
    private final String TASK;
    private String weapon;

    public CounterTerrorist()
    {
        TASK = "DIFFUSE BOMB";
    }
    @Override
    public void assignWeapon(String weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
    @Override
    public void mission()
    {
        System.out.println("Counter Terrorist with weapon "+ weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}

class PlayerFactory
{
    private static HashMap <String, Player> hm =  new HashMap<>();

    public static Player getPlayer(String type)
    {
        Player p = null;

        if (hm.containsKey(type)) {
            p = hm.get(type);
        } else
        {
            switch(type)
            {
            case "Terrorist":
                p = new Terrorist();
                break;
            case "CounterTerrorist":
                p = new CounterTerrorist();
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Unreachable code!");
            }

            hm.put(type, p);
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

The output shows that all Terrorist have the last applied weapon (Maverick) and all CT an AK-47: 
[image]

---

**Edit:** I did not explore this design pattern, but I must say I am not impressed by the code posted in  Geeks For Geeks.
From what I see in [other examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm) the extrinsic attributes need to be managed by the factory. 
In this case I guess the factory should have a map for terrorist and a map for CT where the key is the weapon:

```
public class CounterStrike
{
    //better use enums
    private static String[] playerType = {"Terrorist", "CounterTerrorist"};
    private static String[] weapons = {"AK-47", "Maverick", "Gut Knife", "Desert Eagle"};

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("-------  Construction of Players  ----------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String type = getRandPlayerType();
            Player p = type.equals(playerType[0]) ?  PlayerFactory.getTerrorist(getRandWeapon()) :
                PlayerFactory.getCoubterTerrorist(getRandWeapon()) ;
            p.mission();
            players.add(p);
        }

        System.out.println("-------  Printout all players ----------------");
        for(Player p : players) {
            p.mission();
        }
    }

    public static String getRandPlayerType()
    {
        // Will return 0 or 1
        int randInt =  new Random().nextInt(playerType.length);
        return playerType[randInt];
    }

    public static String getRandWeapon()
    {
        // Will return an integer between 0 inclusive and 5 exclusive
        int randInt = new Random().nextInt(weapons.length);
        return weapons[randInt];
    }
}

class PlayerFactory
{
    private static HashMap <String, Player> terrorists =  new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap <String, Player> cTerrorists =  new HashMap<>();

    public static Player getTerrorist(String weapon)
    {
        Player p = null;

        if (terrorists.containsKey(weapon)) {
            p = terrorists.get(weapon);
        } else{
            p = new Terrorist(weapon);
        }
        terrorists.put(weapon, p);
        return p;
    }

    public static Player getCoubterTerrorist(String weapon)
    {
        Player p = null;

        if (cTerrorists.containsKey(weapon)) {
            p = cTerrorists.get(weapon);
        } else{
            p = new CounterTerrorist(weapon);
        }
        cTerrorists.put(weapon, p);
        return p;
    }
}
interface Player
{
    void mission();
}

class Terrorist implements Player
{
    private final String TASK;
    private String weapon;

    public Terrorist(String weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
        TASK = "PLANT A BOMB";
    }

    @Override
    public void mission()
    {
        System.out.println("Terrorist with weapon " + weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}

class CounterTerrorist implements Player
{
    private final String TASK;
    private String weapon;

    public CounterTerrorist(String weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
        TASK = "DIFFUSE BOMB";
    }

    @Override
    public void mission()
    {
        System.out.println("Counter Terrorist with weapon "+ weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}
```

We can improve the implementation by using enums, and making the player type an intrinsic attribute, rather than a class:

```
public class CounterStrike
{
    public enum PlayerType{

        TERRORIST("PLANT A BOMB"), COUNTER_TERRORIST("DIFFUSE BOMB");

        private final String task;

        PlayerType(String task){
            this.task = task;
        }

        String getTask(){ return task;  }
    }

    public enum Weapon {

        AK47("AK-47"), MAVERICK("Maverick"), GUT_KNIFE("Gut Knife"), DESERT_EAGLE("Desert Eagle");

        private final String name;

        Weapon(String name) {   this.name = name;   }

        String getName(){ return name;  }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return name; }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("-------  Construction of Players  ----------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Player p = PlayerFactory.getPlayer(getRandPlayerType(), getRandWeapon()) ;
            players.add(p);
            System.out.println("Created: "+ p);
        }

        System.out.println("-------  Printout all players ----------------");
        for(Player p : players) {   System.out.println(p);  }
    }

    public static PlayerType getRandPlayerType()
    {
        int randInt =  new Random().nextInt(PlayerType.values().length);
        return PlayerType.values()[randInt];
    }

    public static Weapon getRandWeapon()
    {
        int randInt =  new Random().nextInt(Weapon.values().length);
        return Weapon.values()[randInt];
    }
}

class PlayerFactory
{
    private static HashMap <Weapon, Player> terrorists =  new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap <Weapon, Player> cTerrorists =  new HashMap<>();

    static Player getPlayer(PlayerType type, Weapon weapon) {

        return type == PlayerType.TERRORIST ? getTerrorist(weapon) : getCounterTerrorist(weapon);
    }

    private static Player getTerrorist(Weapon weapon)
    {
        Player p = null;

        if (terrorists.containsKey(weapon)) {
            p = terrorists.get(weapon);
        } else{
            p = new Player(PlayerType.TERRORIST, weapon);
        }
        terrorists.put(weapon, p);
        return p;
    }

    private static Player getCounterTerrorist(Weapon weapon)
    {
        Player p = null;

        if (cTerrorists.containsKey(weapon)) {
            p = cTerrorists.get(weapon);
        } else{
            p = new Player(PlayerType.COUNTER_TERRORIST, weapon);
        }
        cTerrorists.put(weapon, p);
        return p;
    }
}

class Player
{
    private final Weapon weapon;
    private final PlayerType type;

    Player(PlayerType type, Weapon weapon) {
        this.type = type;
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    Weapon getWeapon() { return weapon; }

    PlayerType getType() {return type; }

    String getTask() {  return type.getTask(); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(type == PlayerType.TERRORIST ? "Terrorist" : "Counter Terrorist" );
        sb.append(" armed with ").append(weapon).append(". Task: ").append(type.getTask());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks You. This was helpful. Is it the flyweight pattern's behavior to overwrite extrinsic properties? Is the pattern generally implemented the way it is described in this example?

Comment: This is super helpful. With your improved implementation , if I want to keep track of the players are either terrorist or counter terrorist , I would have to create a name list under those objects to track the player along with weapon. The pattern will help reduce the memory footprint. Please correct me if I am wrong & thanks again for taking the time answer in great detail.

Comment: In the last code I posted players are identified by their weapon. 5 Terrorist, each with a different weapon. The same applies for CT.

Answer (score 1):

In the example class diagram given by the Geeks for Geeks author

[image: Class Diagram]

If I understand this correctly, the game creates one instance of `Terrorist`, one instance of `CounterTerrorist`, and `n` instances of `Player` created by the `PlayerFactory`.

The code reflects the diagram.  `Terrorist` and `CounterTerrorist` implement the `Player` interface.

Each `Player` instance created by the `PlayerFactory` uses the information from the `Terrorist` or `CounterTerrorist` instance, depending on which side the player is on.  Since there's a `Player` instance for each player (Usually 10 in CounterStrike, 5 on each side), there's no confusion as to which player is which.

The `CounterStrike` class manages the `Map` created by the `PlayerFactory`.

This simple real-world example minimizes the duplication that would occur if there were just `n` `Player` instances.  Each `Player` instance would have to hold the information for both a terrorist and a counter-terrorist.

By creating one instance of `Terrorist`, one instance of `CounterTerrorist`, and sharing those instances with the `Player` instances, the total amount of storage for the game fields is reduced.

The game code is probably easier to debug and manage as well.

The Java code can be found on [Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flyweight-design-pattern/).

Comment: Thanks @Gilbert Le Blanc. However it looks like the extrinsic state is overwritten and we have only 2 objects and may not be possibly be able to identify the players uniquely using just the 2 objects. Is the pattern applicable for the use case provided in this example?